# Spit Data in Single Cell into Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with Names and Addresses in an Excel file in following format.

```
Name1
  134/47/1,
adrs1, adr2, country

Name2
 adrs1, adrs2, country 

Name3
  107/c,
adrs3, adrs3, country

etc…
```

I want to split these data into multiple rows in following format

```
Name1
  134/47/1,
adrs1,
adrs2,
country

Name2
 No 134/63,
adrs1,
adrs2,
country


etc…
```

I tried following but it worked for one row cell only.

```
Sub tst()
    Dim X As Variant
    X = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value =         Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

Comment: Anything with a comma is intended to be split?

Comment: Instead of simply extending the current range your macro should add two new lines to your table (if that is, what you *really* want) since otherwise you would overwrite the contents of your next intended input cell. But what about writing a matrix function that returns an array of 4 adjacent cells (vertically or horizontally) and then use that function in another Excel sheet, referencing the original cells?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether your sample data had trailing commas on single values as a typo or if that is what accurately represents your data but that should be accounted for. A rogue comma as a suffix will create an extra element to the variant array thereby throwing off dimensions created by referencing the [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx).

```
Sub split_from_below_space()
    Dim rw As Long, v As Long, vVALs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   'set this worksheet reference properly!
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            .Cells(rw, 1) = Trim(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2)
            If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(rw, 1).Value2, Chr(44) & Chr(32))) Then
                vVALs = Split(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, Chr(44) & Chr(32))
                .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(vVALs), 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(UBound(vVALs) + 1, 1) = _
                    Application.Transpose(vVALs)
                For v = UBound(vVALs) - 1 To LBound(vVALs) Step -1
                    .Cells(rw, 1).Offset(v, 0) = _
                        Trim(.Cells(rw, 1).Offset(v, 0).Value2) & Chr(44)
                Next v
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

You will need to insert rows to accommodate the data and that method is almost always (as in this case) better performed by working from the bottom to the top.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. You saved my day. I have 2 requests though.
1. When we breakdown in to rows, can we include the "," at the end of the string? Example: like following format
Name1,
Adrs1,
Adrs2,
Country

2. If you have time can you explain this code for me?

Really appreciate your help

Comment: 1. The *country* and the *Name* in your example do not have trailing commas. What should receive a comma and what should not? 2. Sorry, there is too much information available on the internet for me to reguritate a portion of it here.

Answer (score 1):

The following macro might help you. You would have to select the **very last** cell in your table containing a multipart address. When you start the macro it will then work its way up to the top and insert address lines where needed (only in the current column) and then exit.

```
Option Base 1
Sub trnsfrm()
  Dim i%, n%, ret(3, 1)
  Set r = Selection
  Do
    a = Split(r, ",")
    ret(1, 1) = Trim(a(0))
    ret(2, 1) = Trim(a(1))
    ret(3, 1) = Trim(a(2))
    r.Range([a2], [a3]).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    r.Range([a1], [a3]) = ret
    If r.Row <= 4 Then Exit Do
    Set r = r.Offset(-4)
  Loop
End Sub
```

If you want to insert lines across the whole table you should replace the line (10)

```
r.Range([a2], [a3]).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

by

```
r.Range([a2], [a3]).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

**Assumptions / Warning**

Since the macro will actually change your current table and 'undo' does not work with macros you should definitely save everything before you try it.

The macro assumes that **each address block** consists of **exactly 4 lines**. If there are fewer or more lines to an address the maro will get out of sync and will very likely output garbage or halt.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help here. It works well. As you said there are some assumptions and Warnings we need to consider. 
But the 1st answer solves my issue. Thanks again for your time.